# Sitecore Solr query: field name translation culture issue

Tags: c#, solr, sitecore

I am wondering if there is anyway to force FieldNameTranslator to append language to the field name.

```cs
query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>(i => i[context.Index.FieldNameTranslator.GetIndexFieldName("Catalog Number")].Contains("m0202"));
```

The code above turns into solr query:

```
https://localhost:8983/solr/sitecore_web_index/select?q=catalog_number_t:(*m0202*)
```

which returns 0 results.

If I append _en to the field name:

```
https://localhost:8983/solr/sitecore_web_index/select?q=catalog_number_t_en:(*m0202*)
```

I am getting expected results.

So how can I add it through the code?

Even

```cs
context.Index.FieldNameTranslator.GetIndexFieldName("catalog_number_t_en")
```

returns catalog_number_t

Catalog Number - single-line text field in sitecore.
I am using Sitecore 9.1 Update-1, Solr 7.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a culture language version stored in a different field name in a Solr index then you can use one of the following overloads in order to append the culture to the end of the field name:

```
string SolrFieldNameTranslator.GetIndexFieldName(string fieldName, CultureInfo culture);
string SolrFieldNameTranslator.GetIndexFieldName(string fieldName, Type returnType, CultureInfo culture);
```